# Unable to chunk PDF document using Langchain PDFLoader

Tags: next.js, langchain, node.js-fs

In my NextJS 14 project, I have a client-side component called **ResearchChatbox.tsx** from which I call a server-side method called **vectorize()** via a `fetch()` request, sending it a URL to a PDF document as argument:

```
"use client"
interface ResearchChatboxProps {
  file: File
}
function ResearchChatbox({ file }: ResearchChatboxProps) {
  const handleGetChunkedDocs = () => {
    fetch("/api/vectorize", {
      method: "POST",
      body: JSON.stringify({ pdfPath: "https://arxiv.org/pdf/2401.06731.pdf" }),
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
    })
      .then((response) => {
        if (response.ok) {
          return response.json()
        }
        console.error(response.statusText)
      })
      .then((data: any) => {
        console.log("CHUNKS: ", data)
      });
  };

  if (file) handleGetChunkedDocs()
}
```

The server-side method (**vectorize.ts**) then retrieves the file from the given URL, parses it using Langchain’s **PDFLoader** and **RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter** functions, and returns the chunks to the client-side component that made the request:

```
import { PDFLoader } from "langchain/document_loaders/fs/pdf"
import { RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter } from "langchain/text_splitter"

export default async function handler(req: any, res: any) {
  const { pdfPath } = req.body

  try {
    const loader = new PDFLoader(pdfPath)
    const docs = await loader.load()

    // From the docs https://www.pinecone.io/learn/chunking-strategies/
    const textSplitter = new RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter({
      chunkSize: 1000,
      chunkOverlap: 200,
    })

    const chunkedDocs = await textSplitter.splitDocuments(docs)

    res.status(200).json(chunkedDocs)
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e)
    res.status(500).json({ error: "PDF docs chunking failed!" })
  }
}
```

When loaded into the browser, however, the component is giving me this error in the console:

> Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', "<!DOCTYPE
> "... is not valid JSON Promise.then (async) handleGetChunkedDocs @
> ResearchChatbox.tsx:29 ResearchChatbox @ ResearchChatbox.tsx:34
> renderWithHooksAgain @ react-dom.development.js:11162 renderWithHooks
> @ react-dom.development.js:11023 updateFunctionComponent @
> react-dom.development.js:16163 beginWork$1 @
> react-dom.development.js:18359 beginWork @
> react-dom.development.js:26741 performUnitOfWork @
> react-dom.development.js:25587 workLoopSync @
> react-dom.development.js:25303 renderRootSync @
> react-dom.development.js:25258 performConcurrentWorkOnRoot @
> react-dom.development.js:24382 workLoop @ scheduler.development.js:261
> flushWork @ scheduler.development.js:230 performWorkUntilDeadline @
> scheduler.development.js:534

How do I fix this? I understand this is due to the file headers that form part of the PDF, but I cannot remove them before chunking. Is there any way to make either the server-side function ignore that bit before chunking, or the client-side function ignore it while reading the response? What else can be done?